# In Flash Builder 4.7, how do I use -define=CONFIG::release,true with Export Release Build?

Tags: flash-builder

I can't seem to find a way to compile my AS3 code/project differently for the release build vs. the debug build using the IDE. Is there a way to set different command-line options for the SWF compiler when using the "Export Release Build" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project > Properties > ActionScript Compiler.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/il2f0kq7i0uvfnl/Screenshot%202014-08-19%2016.32.09.png

You can also find more here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f14.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that's how you change ASC settings, but I believe that's the same for both release and debug builds. I want to have different settings when launching "Export Release Build" vs. the normal Development/Debug build.

Comment: In this case you should look into "Profile Configurations" or create a new "Run Configurations".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I believe that only affects command-line arguments at runtime to the AIR app, not compile-time options.